# Import from Twitter to Google Plus

Tags: twitter, google-plus, integration

I know that you can import from Facebook to Yahoo, and from Yahoo to Google+, but is there any way yet of importing followers and following to Google+ from Twitter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a tool to help with this.  It can find the Google+ profiles of folks that you follow on Twitter.

[Twitter to Google](http://www.twittertoplus.com)

It does rely on those you follow on Twitter having a [www.gplus.to](http://www.gplus.to) Google+ nickname that matches their Twitter name.

Currently it will find around 20% of those that you follow, but this can be increased simply by spreading the word, e.g. via tweets, that Twitter users should go and grab their matching gplus name.

Comment: Congrats, what an amazing tool!

Answer (score 5):

At the moment this is not possible. I would imagine that when the Google+ API becomes publicly available to Developers there will be a influx of new Applications that can interact with Google+